# NSFontManager selectedFont returning null

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsfontpanel, nsfontmanager

Okay so I've checked all over S.O. and all over Google and I can't find what is wrong with my code:

```
- (IBAction)selectFont:(id)sender
{
    NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    [fontManager setDelegate:self];
    [fontManager setTarget:self];

    NSFontPanel *fontPanel = [fontManager fontPanel:YES];
    [fontPanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}

- (void)changeFont:(id)sender
{
    NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    font = [fontManager selectedFont];
    NSLog(@"%@",[fontManager selectedFont]);
}
```

The font panel pops up, but when I select a font, the console returns `(null)` for the selected font of the Font Manager. Anyone know what I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/changeFont%3a) says that using `selectedFont` in `changeFont:` could result in unexpected behavior and "*The use of selectedFont from within changeFont: is strongly discouraged.*"  The appropriate way to get a font from `NSFontPanel` is to ask `NSFontManager` to convert the current font into the selected font. Here is an example application that properly uses `NSFontPanel`:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>{
    NSFont *font;
}

- (IBAction)selectFont:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    font = [NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
}

- (IBAction)selectFont:(id)sender
{
    NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    [fontManager setDelegate:self];
    [fontManager setTarget:self];
    [fontManager orderFrontFontPanel:self];
}

- (void)changeFont:(id)sender
{
    font = [sender convertFont:font];
    NSLog(@"%@", font);
}
```

I've removed bits and pieces of the code that aren't relevant to your problem (such as IBOutlets to NSButtons and the NSWindow).
Please note this example uses ARC.

Another thing that is important to know is that the argument to `convertFont:` needs to be a valid `NSFont` instance. Otherwise, `convertFont:` will return nil even though a font has been selected in the `NSFontPanel`.  For this reason, it's important to initialize the `NSFont *font` instance variable to an valid `NSFont` instance.

Comment: Huh, I have no idea why converting my existing font variable works...but okay. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A common misconception is that NSFontPanel is used to create a new font object. From 'Cocoa Programming - Developers Handbook' by David Chisnall, "The font panel is more complicated. It sends updates to the font manager. This is a central part of the Cocoa text system, responsible for handling interactions with font conversions.  When you adjust a property in the font panel, it does not create a new font description.  The font panel and NSFontManager keep track of the changes that have been made to the font. On line 21, we make use of this by sending a convert: message to the font manager."